# Как перепрограммировать клавишу ноутбука в Linux?

Tags: linux, клавиатура, ноутбук

Как глобально (т е без привязки к вообще графической подсистеме) переопределить клавишу ноутбука?

У меня на ноутбуке есть клавиша для программы Xiaomi Assistant (или как там эту программу для сяоми ноутбуков). По изначальному её предназначению мне она не нужна, но у меня на клавиатуре ноутбука нету клавиши SysRq, а вот она мне нужна. Думал перепрограммировать клавишу. Вот что пишет `dmesg` при нажатии на клавишу:

```
[99999.99999] atkbd serio0: unknown key pressed (translated set 2, code 0xf2 on isa0060/serio0)
[99999.99999] atkbd serio0: Use 'setkeycodes e072 <keycode>' to make it known
```

Пробую перепрограммировать через setkeycodes:

```
 ~ # setkeycodes e072 ff15
Error reading scancode
 ~ # showkey
# Now, I'm pressing Xiaomi Assistant key...
# No keycode!!!
 ~ #
```

А толку 0

Есть ли способ - через user или kernel space (на худой конец, написать модуль ядра, который бы перехватывал именно данную клавишу) переопределить клавишу, которая своего реального назначения все равно не выполняет? И да, xkbmap или его аналоги на Wayland мне не нужны, мне нужно переопределить клавишу на системном уровне, без привязки к графической среде (тем более, речь тут идёт о критически важной клавише SysRq).

Comment: вместо `e072` попробуй `0xf2` ::: `# setkeycodes 0xf2 ...` см. [Keyboard_input#Using_dmesg](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Keyboard_input#Using_dmesg). Второй параметр `ff15` похоже тоже не совсем верен `setkeycodes <scancode> <keycode>` где  `<scancode>` шеснадцатиричный а `<keycode>` десятиричный. man setkeycodes -- _The setkeycodes command reads its arguments two at a time, each pair of arguments consisting of a scancode (given in hexadecimal) and a keycode (given in decimal)._ Вместо  `showkey` попробуй `evtest` [Using_evtest](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Keyboard_input#Using_evtest)

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Насчёт SysRq код оказался вообще не тот (check `/usr/include/linux/input-event-codes.h`, line 174)